# Is MCOIMAPSearchOperation with searchSinceReceivedDate time specific or granular?

Tags: mailcore2

Below is the code I have to do a search using searchSinceReceivedDate.

It will return all the messages for a given date.

I want to know if the method also uses the hour, minute , second portion of the NSDate?

So that I can say I want to retrieve all new messages in the last 5 minutes.

```
MCOIMAPSearchExpression *dateFilter = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchSinceReceivedDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds]];
MCOIMAPSearchOperation *searchOperation = [session searchExpressionOperationWithFolder:folder expression:dateFilter];
```

Below is the debug output of the interaction:

```
2014-08-01 08:36:52.753 myApp[3154:360f] - 1 - 8 UID SEARCH SINCE 1-Aug-2014
```

Comment: Hello Timothy, Did MCOIMAPSearchExpression working for you?

Comment: I have some issue in it. You can check it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419485/fetch-gmails-email-from-past-30-days-using-mailcore-and-mcoimapsearchoperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I received from the mailcore2 forum was that I am to use the last uuid as a basis for my next search.

This worked for me.